# How to modify JLabel on JTabbedPane tab?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtabbedpane

So say you had a JTabbedPane. And on each of those tabs, you have a JPanel with a JLabel, and a JButton. How can you modify that JLabel's text after it's already been added to the pane?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jLabelN.setText("New Text");` as usual. It does not matter where the label is added to. You just need your variable jLabelN to be accessible.

Comment: Ah. I had a method that did all of the managing of setting up the tab,so every label had the same name, but i got it worked out just like you said, rather simple. Thank you.

Comment: @nyx: Please consider accepting this answer; see the [faq] for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write getters and setters for your GUI components like a (just some snippets)

```
public class A extends JPanel{

    JLabel aLabel=new JLabel();//field

    public A(){ 

     this.add(aLabel);

//GUI init here...
  }



    public void setLabelText(String text)
    {
      this.aLabel.setText(text);
    }

    public String getLabelText(){return this.aLabel.getText(); }
...
}
```

Lets call it now as...

```
public class B extends JFrame
{
A a=new A(); //
A a1=new A();

JTabbedPane tp=new JTabbedPane();

public B()
{

a.setLabelText("Hello World!");
a1.setLabelText("Hello World Again!");

tb.add("tab 0", a);
tb.add("tab 1", a1);
//    ...
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  /*a button clicked...
    Lets get the tab label text value */

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"tab 0 label text is: "+this.a.getLabelText());
  this.a.setLabelText("Have a good Java Coding");
}

}
```

Using getters and setters it is a standard way of objects data interaction

Good luck